# LMD/Maldetect: Missing target-file operand after

Tags: malware, mv, malicious

After running mallet 1.5 in screen-mode (# maldet -a /var/www) I'm getting this return:

```
maldet(6070): {scan} 618017/618044 files scanned: hits 0 cleaned/usr/bin/wc: /usr/local/maldetect/tmp/.sess.6070: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
maldet(6070): {scan} 618018/618044 files scanned: hits 0 cleaned/usr/bin/wc: /usr/local/maldetect/tmp/.sess.6070: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
maldet(6070): {scan} 618019/618044 files scanned: hits 0 cleaned/usr/bin/wc: /usr/local/maldetect/tmp/.sess.6070: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
maldet(6070): {scan} 618020/618044 files scanned: hits 0 cleaned/usr/bin/wc: /usr/local/maldetect/tmp/.sess.6070: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
maldet(6070): {scan} 618021/618044 files scanned: hits 0 cleaned/usr/bin/wc: /usr/local/maldetect/tmp/.sess.6070: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
mv: Fehlender Zieldatei‐Operand hinter „/usr/local/maldetect/tmp/.sess.6070“
„mv --help“ liefert weitere Informationen.
```

This means:

```
/usr/local/maldetect/tmp/.sess.6070: File or folder not found
...
mv: Missing target-file operand after „/usr/local/maldetect/tmp/.sess.6070“
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?